# Handling conflicting ROS package versions: Need guidance

Tags: ros2, ros-foxy

I'm encountering a dependency conflict with my ROS package, [`baggie`](https://github.com/Box-Robotics/ros2-bagutils). It requires `rosbag2_cpp`, `rosbag2_compression`, and `rosbag2_storage`. However, the standard `rosbag2` in ROS 2 Foxy lacks some essential features I need. So, I built the [`rosbag2`](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/tree/foxy-future) package from source (`foxy_future` branch) to address this. Unfortunately, it interferes with the standard [`rosbag2`](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/tree/foxy-future), causing [`baggie`](https://github.com/Box-Robotics/ros2-bagutils) to fail during runtime.

How can I instruct [`baggie`](https://github.com/Box-Robotics/ros2-bagutils) to use the standard [`rosbag2`](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/tree/foxy-future) version while allowing the other packages to utilize the newer version I built?

Ideally, I would like to have all the packages within the same workspace for better git control and ease of building. However, despite several days of effort, I am open to having them in different workspaces. In that case, it would be extremely helpful if I could source them simultaneously to simplify my workflow.

Appreciate any help or suggestions. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Platform:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- ROS version: ROS 2 Foxy